# MAX7219 only displaying on first digit

Tags: arduino-uno, max7219

I'm trying to display a scrolling number on my MAX7219 display using the LedControl library, but can only ever get the first digit (digit 0) updating. When I reference digits 1-7 the 7 segments don't light up.

This also happens even with the example sketch LCDemo7Segment. Is there an issue with my display unit perhaps?

Using an Uno board and [this](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/9285639274526/XC3714-manualMain.pdf) module. Using pin 11 for DataIn, 13 for CLK, and 12 for Load.

Comment: Can you post more data on the display you are using (model, schematic, picture, link)?

Comment: Done now :) I know the link doesn't provide a great deal of data but it's all you get from the supplier

Comment: Did you try the [software](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/9285639307294/XC3714-softwareMain.zip) the producer is giving you, of course making the connections suggested by him (DIN 4, CS 5, CLK 6)?

Comment: Alright I get all displays lighting up now, so it's not a hardware issue, just software. Is there anything I can change in the LedControl library to restore function?

Comment: honestly I do not know that library. Maybe you can try comparing the two codes, and make changes until the library works...

Comment: Maybe you should ask the author of the library by creating an [issue on the Github repository](https://github.com/wayoda/LedControl/issues)